# I can I map from a string to a constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor

I have string inputs, and depending on the value of that input, I'd like to call a specific object's constructor (**new Object1(int), new Object2(string), new Object3(int, int)**, etc. all implementing an IObject interface).

Rather than doing this the obvious (and slow) way of chaining if/else statements, I'd like to do something like having a Dictionary that goes from a string to a constructor (e.g. {"object1" -> new Object1(int)} )

Is there some way I can do something like this in C#, perhaps through combining "typeof" with a constructor?  I'd like to avoid a Factory, as that'd require parallel code structures, which I'd like to avoid.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You want to construct the object and then immediately throw it away?

Comment: Use Type.GetConstructor() to get a ConstructorInfo.  Use its Invoke method to create the type.  Or use Activator.CreateInstance().

Comment: You think a few if statements is slower than creating a spurious instance of an object?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I absolutely do not want to throw it away.  I didn't mean to imply that.

Comment: @EdS: A chain of O(1) statements is definitely going to slower than a single O(1) statement.  Either way, I meant slower/dirtier to code, and less maintainable.

Comment: @Benjin: That's not true at all. O(1) simply means constant time. That time may be 1 nanosecond or 1 second.  That doesn't mean I think it's the best solution (though, factory methods are typically implemented as a big switch statement), but don't just assume it is slower.

Comment: @EdS. True, I mispoke.  I expect the number of mappings that need to be done to grow, which would stay constant in the same run, but between runs would expand.  Not really the usual use of big-O notation, I realize.  Even so, I would think a hash (where adding a new entry is a single, brace-less line) is a cleaner solution, no?

Comment: @Benjin: Yeah, so I was picking apart/harping on the performance comment, but you're probably right in thinking it's not the best solution.  The question actually confuses me a bit; you say *" I'd like to call a specific object's constructor"*, but in your example you use `new Object1(), new Object2(), new Object3(), etc`, which is actually a parameterless constructor of *three different types*, not three different constructors of *the same type*, which changes the problem a bit.  Also, a `switch` statement can offer constant time execution regardless of how many checks there are.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10444/discussion-between-benjin-and-ed-s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, Func<IObject>>();
d.Add("Object1", () => new Object1());
d.Add("Object2", () => new Object2());
d.Add("Object3", () => new Object3());
string typename = GetAStringFromSomewhere();
IObject foo = d[typename]();
```

Comment: Simple and avoids reflection.

Comment: Looks like it should do exactly what I want.  Random question that I've been wondering for a few weeks: why is it preferable to use "var d" instead of "Dictionary<string, Func<IObject>> d" there?

Comment: Also, how would I adapt this so that the constructors take arguments?  (Each constructor takes a different number and type of arguments)

Comment: `var d` is because the other one is too long to type twice... Where would you get the values for the constructor arguments from?  If they're fixed, you can just insert them directly in the above code...

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

In particular, [Assembly.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.createinstance.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

How about difining a static method to create an object for each class you want, and than, use a dictionary mapping string to a delegate type of the static producer method? Well, I know this is not exactly what your question want, but I can't comment on you question now.

```
class Program
{
    delegate object GetObjDelegate();
    static Dictionary<string, GetObjDelegate> Dic = new Dictionary<string, GetObjDelegate>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dic.Add("aaa", A.GetObj);
        Dic.Add("bbb", B.GetObj);

        object a = Dic["aaa"]();
        object b = Dic["bbb"]();
    }
}

class A
{
    public A()
    {
    }

    public static A GetObj()
    {
        return new A();
    }
}

class B
{
    public B()
    {
    }

    public static B GetObj()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```